# RadGrid Progressbar while loading the data

Tags: telerik

I have a RadGrid with 10 Columns and 1000s of Rows. The loading takes sometime and in the meantime, I would like to display round circle progressing. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must add the RadAjaxManager and RadAjaxLoadingPanel

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGrid1">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel runat="server" ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1"></telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
<div class="demo-container no-bg">
    <telerik:RadGrid RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowSorting="True"
        AllowPaging="True" GridLines="None" Width="100%">
        <PagerStyle Mode="Slider" Position="TopAndBottom" PageSizeControlType="RadComboBox"></PagerStyle>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use the RadAjaxloadingPanel from Telerik

There's plenty of examples over at Telerik.

https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ajaxloadingpanel/overview/defaultcs.aspx